# Is there a way to set up EventBridge Rule to catch event only from specific(parameterized) branch from codecommit

Tags: amazon-web-services, templates, yaml, aws-cloudformation, aws-event-bridge

so the goal is to catch event from EventBridge when Codecommit pull request happens from a specific repository and specific branch. Then get notification on email via SNS. Email, repo, branch must be parameterized.

I am getting email notification on a repository level, but when I tried to make pull request from other branch than is defined, I am still getting notification.

This is my EventBridge rule now - Branch is hardcoded as referencName: preprod (for now)
Thanks for any suggestions

```
  MyEventBridgeRule:
Type: AWS::Events::Rule
Properties:
  EventBusName: default
  EventPattern:
    source:
      - aws.codecommit
    detail-type:
      - 'CodeCommit Repository State Change'
    resources:
      - !Ref ParamRepository
    detail:
      event:
        - referenceCreated
        - referenceUpdated
      referenceType:
        - branch
      referenceName:
        - preprod
```